# How to manipulate wx.ProgressDialog using wx.Python

Tags: wxpython, python-2.7

actually I got a bunch of questions about wx.ProgressDialog in wx.Python.

First of all I have written a piece of code that opes 2 files does some calculations and writes the results in a new file. What I need to show in GUI is a progress dialog in indeterminate mode only for the user to understand that the programm is running.

```
def transformation(e):
     prg_dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Processing Data", "Time elapsed", style = wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME)

     for line in pntfile.readlines():
              pntlist = line.split(" ")
              pntlist = [float(i) for i in pntlist]


              l = ( const + Xn*pntlist[0] + Yn*pntlist[1] + Zn*pntlist[2])/(Xn**2 * Yn**2 * Zn**2)


              Xm = pntlist[0] - Xn*l
              Ym = pntlist[1] - Yn*l
              Zm = pntlist[2] - Zn*l

              outlist=[0,0,0]  


              outlist[0] = pntlist[0] / 2*(Xm-pntlist[0])
              outlist[1] = pntlist[1] / 2*(Ym-pntlist[1])
              outlist[2] = pntlist[2] / 2*(Zm-pntlist[2])


              outdata = str('%.4f' %outlist[0])+" "+str('%.4f' %outlist[1])+" "+str('%.4f' %outlist[2])+"\n"


              outfile.writelines(outdata)      

              prg_dlg.UpdatePulse()

     wx.Yield()    
     pntfile.close()    
     outfile.close()
```

1. When I run the full application the progress dialog appears and the gauge goes back and forth way too fast, almost impossible to see (tested on MS WIN VISTA, 7, XP, UBUNTU)
2. I would like to place a button on the dialog (e.g. OK) so that when the program finishes with the calculations the user can press it and the dialog can close
3. Most important is the performance. When I run the program using 1million lines in the input file **without** the progress dialog, it finishes in less than a minute. When using the dialog as it is shown in the code above, it takes more than 4 minutes to finish. How could I speed it up?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Run the computation in a separate thread, and send un update message to the progress dialog every 1000 lines or so.

Note that you need to use CallAfter or an Event as you cannot call a wxPython function in a thread.

When done, simply close the progress Dialog and show a simple message box with an OK button.

Comment: I suppose that the gauge goes too fast because it updates itself for every single line of the file which means every single calculation?

Comment: @AlexTh: Yes, if you use the `UpdatePulse()` method the gauge will advance a little bit for each call. So you should limit you updates to say ounce or twice a second.

Comment: Could you please a way I could do that? I'm still learning the language.I still want it to run in indeterminate mode and as soon as the calculations end the bar stops